# Protected Question does not show Add an Answer button

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, protected-questions

This question is protected. To answer it, I must have at least 10 reputation.

> [Word meaning "to walk clumsily among many obstacles"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/202732/45721)

Ignoring the association bonus of 100, I should [at least have 73](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/45721/adtc?tab=reputation).

Yet, the Android app does not show the blue "Add an Answer" button at the bottom. The app also does not show the protection status.

If I view the question in the desktop or mobile browser (and I'm signed in), I can add an answer there.

Comment: App even doesn't show that question is protected.

Comment: Thanks @nicael. I have added that.

Comment: Well, iOS app does show a banner that it's protected but also doesn't allow adding answer. Looks like both apps assume that if a question got a "notice", it can't be answered.

Comment: I am running into the same issue - very annoying because protected questions are often interesting but do not always have a great answer... How come there is no apparent response from the development team on this?

Comment: @Floris only one developer, and there are probably more urgent bugs. (e.g. [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260498/app-keeps-crashing-rendering-error-since-update-to-1-0-68))

Comment: @ShadowWizard sure - but since this bug seems to be common across platforms there should be a common fix so really we have two developers... Usually there is at least an ACK from the dev team but here - nothing?

Comment: @Floris actually there's ACK from the team in <1% of the bugs.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I must have been unusually lucky in a he past then. Thanks for the dose of reality.

Answer (score 3):

We used to have a really complex and super annoying way of checking user permissions for most things (e.g. checking for mod-ship, reputation, etc all on the client side) -- Since then, our API has gotten a `can_answer` attribute on questions (which we're already using on iOS).

As of any version greater than 1.0.81, we now use this field rather than doing the check for if you can answer on the client side. This means you will now see an "Add Answer" button on posts that are protected. You should see version 1.0.82 hitting the beta tier later today or tomorrow.