# Preferred way to report the same bug in multiple apps?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, mobile-app

A little ago, I found [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242281/protected-question-does-not-show-add-an-answer-button) in the review queue. The asker is reporting a bug he found in the android SE app.

The suggested edit proposed to add a second tag to the question to indicate that the bug seem to be present on the IOS app too. I approved the edit and added that info to the question.

Soon after, an user on the Tavern chat room made me notice that this way the staff can't actually mark the bug as fixed until both app are fixed. I am left now wondering... what is the preferred way to handle this situation? Have two copy of the question, each one referencing to one app?

I am especially interested in any info that can provide indication about the staff preferences, ie - finding the posting pattern that is simpler for them to manage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Kasra](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/229741/kasra-rahjerdi?tab=profile) of our Mobile Team, one [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) report is sufficient if it is reasonably apparent that it is the *same* problem in both platforms.

You can read more about the (updated) policy in this post:

[**Separate bug posts for a same mobile issue recommended?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276146/creating-separate-bug-posts-for-a-same-issue-for-android-app-and-ios-app-is-reco)

Answer (score 7):

I think it is best to keep things separate. As a CTO of a software company I know how hard it is to manage bug reports that span products where the original cause of the issue isn't shared. You can't mark one fixed and the other not.

You should separate things as much as possible if it isn't clear if the issue is the exact same. If for example, like in this case, the issue is present in both the iOS and Android app, create two bug reports. You could state the problem is the same as you have seen in the other app. That might help the developer to analyse the problem if they are related.

Comment: According to the mobile team, it's actually preferable to post ***one* bug report** in this situation. See the (new) duplicate post.

Comment: Thanks for the ping back.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Can you add a wiki comunity answer here so that I can point to the correct solution? I fear some people looking at this post may not notice the dupe or don't bother to click...