# No way to know that a question is protected in the Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, protected-questions

I'm trying to answer a question via the Android app, but I can't seem to find an answer button or instructions / reasons for why there isn't one.

I see the question and its existing answers, but simply no "Add Answer" button anywhere, and no banner/message explaining why.

I later realized the question is protected, and I can see this in the mobile web or iOS app, but not in the Android app.

Please fix it and show a message saying the question is protected in the Android app as well.

**Note**: whatever was done in *[Protected Question does not show Add an Answer button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242281/protected-question-does-not-show-add-an-answer-button)* has been reverted at some point and is not relevant.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect - given your recently-suggested edit - that you were looking at [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/279072/people-who-treat-living-things-with-kindness-and-love-word-term).

It is a "protected" question, and no new answers are provided unless you've already participated *elsewhere on the site* and earned at least 10 reputation points that way. This is done to reduce the volume of spam and chatter on very popular questions.

I honestly have no idea how these questions appear on the mobile app; if you wouldn't mind capturing a screenshot, that'd be helpful.

Comment: I literally got an account to provide the OP with a clearer, more satisfying answer only to be prevented without clear, satisfying context as to why. *sigh*

Comment: @Rashid is correct, I just checked and there is nothing when the question is protected: no answer button, no message saying the question is protected, nada.

Comment: Anyway, turned this into bug report, if you'll ever become android developer guess you can take this as nice programming challenge, Shog. :)

Comment: When looking at question lists (but not on the question itself), protected questions show with "[protected]" appended to their title.

Answer (score 3):

There's specific cases, usually with a fairly visible reason where you can't answer a question. Either the question is closed or on hold, being off topic or needing some sort of fix, or protected, where it has had many answers that weren't very good, and you need some reputation on the site to answer.

[image]

That's on the app.

[image]

And on mobile view. Its pretty intuitive.

Comment: It's possible he stumbled upon a protected question too.

Comment: Are we able to close questions, restricting access to potential, incoming answers?

Comment: Ah that's true. Might be helpful to know what question (s) are involved

Comment: @RashidMBey Questions that are "on hold"  or "closed" can not be answered by anyone. "Protected" questions can not be answered without 10 local reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that [@Shog9's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312744/215590) is right about the question you are looking at, you should be able to see on your mobile that the question is protected:

[image]

Using my iPhone 5s, I can see the Answer button on it, but I have a rep of 202 on that site, and "[Protected questions can only be answered by users with at least 10 reputation (110 if they have the association bonus)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/protected-questions/info)".

[image]

Comment: Not relevant. OP use the android app which is inferior to the iOS app and has about 99% less features.

Comment: OP said that he can see that the question is protected in the iOS app. "I can see this in the mobile web or iOS app". Kindly read the question clearly.

Comment: @KolappanNathan Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/312741/3 - that information was only added by a third party (not the asker) nearly 7 hours after my answer was posted

Comment: @PolyGeo Extremely sorry for my earlier comment. Didn't know that.